# Incomplete type in c++

Tags: c++

I have declared DynArray var_name in c++, but while compiling it gives me an error "incomplete type not allowed"
I tried to search but nothing came up with an example of dynamic array.
Could anyone please explain the error?
Thanks.

Comment: //temp.h
Private: DynArray<string> the_array;
//temp.cpp
in constructor
the_array.append("hello");

Comment: @anjali: edit your answer, paste in code, then highlight code and press `{}` button to indent it, then resubmit

Answer (score 2):

If you are defining a member variable `x` to your class `C` in a header file `C.h` , you must include the header of the class `X` (`X.h`) in `C.h` . If however, you are just storing a pointer to `X` as a member of `C`, then you can forward declare `class X;` before you declare `class C{...};` and then in the definition file `C.cpp`, you must include `X.h` if you access any members of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

"incomplete type not allowed" usually means that a class has been declared but not defined at a point at which its complete definition is needed.

This sometimes happens because of a circular dependency in the headers,

class A's definition depends on class B's definition and visa-versa - causing A.h to include B.h, and then B.h try's to include A.h but can't because the header guard is already defined, so it skips, but then only gets a fwd decl of A.